# How to get bytes [u8; 32] from AccountId?

Tags: accountdata, convert

There is a way to convert [u8; 32] to AccountId

```
T::AccountId::decode(&mut &bytes[..]).unwrap_or_default();
```

but how to do the reverse?

```
let sender: T::AccountId = ensure_signed(origin)?;

let account_bytes: [u8; 32] = sender; //mismatched types
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`From<AccountId32>` is implemented for `[u8; 32]` as you can see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/94dfe152e61e42cd27844a65165cfdedde5232eb/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L551) in the Substrate code, so you can do:

```rust
let account_bytes: [u8; 32] = sender.into();
```

Comment: the trait `From<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>` is not implemented for `[u8; 32]`.  i got this error

Answer (score 1):

For more details, how `AccountId` turns out to be `AccountId32` ? You can follow the following path:

1. in xxxx/runtime.rs(which use to config your node's runtime), you can find following code:

   pub type AccountId = <::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
2. See the definition of `<<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId`, you'll get

   type AccountId = AccountId32;